# Flutter UI Place button on the edge of two containers

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

[image]

How to create an UI like above just the part where the Edit Profile button is on the edge of both the containers ? I used stack and positioned but didnt work out for me . Can somebody help me with this . How to approach this .

Answer (score 0):

try this code no perfect but it will give you some idea

```
Container(
  height: double.infinity,
  width: double.infinity,
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 300.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  blurRadius: 8.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 5.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30.0,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: const <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Year',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Sophmor',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 34.0,
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                    fontFamily: ''),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: const <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Year',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Sophmor',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 34.0,
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                    fontFamily: ''),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: const <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Year',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Sophmor',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 34.0,
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                    fontFamily: ''),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),                ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: const Text('Edit Profile'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ]),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Stack` you can use `Transform.translate` to shift the `TextButton` up by the half of its height:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                color: Color(0xFFF09384),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                color: Color(0xFF3E8C92),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset(0,-35/2), // Here you insert the half of the button height
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => print("Hello"),
                        child: Text("Edit Profile"),
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          fixedSize: Size(120, 35), // Here you should fix the size of the button
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          primary: Color(0xFF3E8C92),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ...List<Text>.filled(5, Text("Data"))
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```